# Google App Script - How to Speed up/Best Practices/Suggestions

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have this section of code that loops through each row on a sheet, approx 15k rows and formats/protects the sheet based.   It works great however it is extremely slow.   I would like to understand a better way to do this.   The big problem is the ranges for these actions are not contiguous and so I am not sure the best way to handle this in batches thus speeding up the code.

As an example, rng(variable) changes every row however in this case it repeats every 4 rows. Not sure if there is a good way to deal with data laid out in this manner. Ideally, instead of a loop I could write  a single line of code that formats all the same rng(variable) in a single command.

```
  for  (var x = 8;  x < (last_row_cur + 8) ; x++)  
 {
      var rng  = sht.getRange(x,7,1,1);
      var rng2 = sht.getRange(x,7,1,15);   
      var rng3 = sht.getRange(x,7,1,6);  //need to update each month  gray
      var rng4 = sht.getRange(x,13,1,7) //need to update each month   green
      var rng5 = sht.getRange(x,1,1,21); 
      var rng6 = sht.getRange(x,20,1,2);
      var rng7 = sht.getRange(x,1,1,12);     
   
       if (rng.getValue() == "Bookings Last Year (FY20)")
       { rng2.setBackground("#f9cb9c"); 
        rng5.setBorder(true,true,null,true,null,null,"black",SpreadsheetApp.BorderStyle.SOLID_THICK);
        var protection = rng5.protect();
            protection.removeEditors(protection.getEditors());
            if (protection.canDomainEdit()) {
            protection.setDomainEdit(false);}
       
       }
       else if (rng.getValue() == "Bookings Plan (AOP)")
       {rng2.setBackground("#cfe2f3");
        rng5.setBorder(null,true,null,true,null,null,"black",SpreadsheetApp.BorderStyle.SOLID_THICK);
        var protection = rng2.protect();
            protection.removeEditors(protection.getEditors());
            if (protection.canDomainEdit()) {
            protection.setDomainEdit(false);}
       } 
       else if (rng.getValue() == "Bookings Actual (YTD)")
       {rng2.setBackground("#d9d9d9");
        rng5.setBorder(null,true,null,true,null,null,"black",SpreadsheetApp.BorderStyle.SOLID_THICK);
        var protection = rng2.protect(); 
                       protection.removeEditors(protection.getEditors());
            if (protection.canDomainEdit()) {
            protection.setDomainEdit(false);}
       }   
       else if (rng.getValue() == "Bookings Forecast (rest of year)")
       {rng3.setBackground("#d9d9d9");
        rng6.setBackground("#d9d9d9");
       rng5.setBorder(null,true,true,true,null,null,"black",SpreadsheetApp.BorderStyle.SOLID_THICK);
       var protection = rng7.protect();         
            protection.removeEditors(protection.getEditors());
            if (protection.canDomainEdit()) {
            protection.setDomainEdit(false);}
       var protection = rng6.protect();
                  protection.removeEditors(protection.getEditors());
            if (protection.canDomainEdit()) {
            protection.setDomainEdit(false);}
     }
   
       if (rng.getValue() == "Bookings Forecast (rest of year)")
       {rng4.setBackground("#d9ead3");         
       }
     }
```

Comment: Are you able to share a sample sheet? Problem with what you are doing I think, is that borders and protections can't be operator on in bulk like values and formatting.  Maybe if you can also provide some context I could try and think of some workaround.

Answer (score 0):

I rewrite the entire function using this sort of approach

```
function myfunction() {
  const ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sht=ss.getSheetByName('sheetname')
  let vs=sh.getRange(8,1,sh.getLastRow()-7,22);
  vs.forEach((row,i)=>{
    let rownummber=i+8;
    //add the rest of the appropriate code yourself
  });
}
```